# How do I read a text file as a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a large text file like this separated into different lines:

35 4 23 12 8 \n
23 6 78 3 5 \n
27 4 9 10 \n
73 5 \n

I need to convert it to a list of lists, each line a separate element like this:

[[35, 4, 23, 12, 8], [23, 6, 78, 3, 5], [27, 4, 9, 10], [73, 5], .......]

Comment: Use `split` on the `\n`s first and then on the whitespaces

Comment: This is basic input processing.  Search for a Python tutorial on the topic that fits your learning level.  Look for the `readline` and `split` methods.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for...

```
with open('file_to_read.csv', 'rU') as f:
        l1 = []
        for ele in f:
            line = ele.split('\n')
            l1.append(line)
print(l1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just be able to use the `genfromtxt` method in `numpy` to do so.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt 
lol = genfromtxt('myFile.csv', delimiter=' ')
```

Find more information [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = [line.split() for line in open('yourtextfile.txt')]  # opens the text file and calls .split() on every line, effectively splitting on every space, creating a list of numbers.
```

Alternatively, the following will also convert your values to int:

```
lines = [[int(v) for v in line.split()] for line in open('yourtextfile.txt')] # opens the text file and calls .split() on every line, effectively splitting on every space, creating a list of numbers that are converted to int()
```